# Grouping Elements in angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I want to use month as the column, location as the row header and then the center item is as value. but unable to make it. 
I want to make a matrix form table, like below:**[image]
my Json is as below:

```js
//Output is as below....{ "QATAR": 464785, "UAE": 223428, "SAUDI ARABIA": 355212 }
$scope.resArray = [{
    "Month": "January-2016",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Value": 26000,
    "Location": "QATAR"
  },
  {
    "Month": "January-2016",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Value": 0,
    "Location": "QATAR"
  },
  {
    "Month": "January-2016",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Value": 8700,
    "Location": "UAE"
  },
  {
    "Month": "January-2016",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Value": 311912,
    "Location": "SAUDI ARABIA"
  },{"Month": "January-2016","Year": "2016","Value": 15300,"Location":SAUDI ARABIA"},{"Month": "January-2016","Year": "2016","Value": 3000,"Location": "QATAR"},{"Month": "January-2016","Year": "2016","Value": 2500,"Location": "QATAR"},{"Month": "January-2016","Year": "2016","Value": 2300,"Location": "UAE"
  }]var groupedData = {};$scope.resArray.forEach(function(item) {var Location = item.Location;var value = item.Value;if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(Location)) {groupedData[Location] += value;
  } else {groupedData[Location] = value;}});
```

**Please see the plunker [PlunkerLink](https://plnkr.co/edit/5r19zOGn18ZzFcYABbSg?p=preview**)

Comment: Any comment on the above question please.

Comment: create a working plunker so that we can get what is the issue actually.

Comment: **pro.mean**, I have no idea about creating the plunker, can we discuss here itself

Comment: open https://plnkr.co/ and click to *launch the editor* and paste the relevant HTML, CSS and JS code there. you can add the angularJS within it from Popular packages tab

Comment: select which version of angular Js you are currently using from the package list

Comment: **pro.mean**, Ok Just give me a minute I will prepare then msg you. be there please.

Comment: **pro.mean**, Can you please check the link. **[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/5r19zOGn18ZzFcYABbSg?p=preview)**

Comment: yes checking now. add this link to your question also.

Comment: **pro.mean**, Sorry If I am not able to make a working plunker, because this is the first time I am working with this plunker.

Comment: No problem, it will help to understand and recreate the solution.

Comment: **pro.mean**, Thanks, Are you making any changes in the plunker?

Comment: yes. but your final output of data will contain only `CITY_NAME: count_sum` then how we show month and year?

Comment: **pro.mean**, Actually I just started to try, but exactly I dont know how to make proper code in javascript.

Comment: we need final `newTable` structure. no matter how to manipulate it

Comment: see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BRt8zIfAeeGJnoz6A3NK?p=preview) and add more data

Comment: **pro.mean**, I am not getting what we are doing in the last plunker.?

Comment: I have just added the comment and make it angular js compatible by adding ng-app in HTML, you can see the console for the final output of your array.

Comment: **pro.mean**, Which plunker has the final output of array?

Comment: that you have decide what will be final output. you current array has only one month data. please share the final desiredarray

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest to use more than one object for grouping, one for grouping by `Month` and `Location` and another one for collection groups specific totals, like for the before mentioned groups and a total value. This is necessary to calculate the percent values, later.

In the result table, you could address the grouped values by taking row and column name for the result.

```js
var $scope = { resArray: [{ Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 26000, Location: "QATAR" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 0, Location: "QATAR" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 8700, Location: "UAE" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 311912, Location: "SAUDI ARABIA" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 15300, Location: "SAUDI ARABIA" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 3000, Location: "QATAR" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 2500, Location: "QATAR" }, { Month: "January-2016", Year: "2016", Value: 2300, Location: "UAE" }] },
    grouped = {},
    total = { total: 0 };

$scope.resArray.forEach(function (item) {
    grouped[item.Month] = grouped[item.Month] || {};
    grouped[item.Month][item.Location] = (grouped[item.Month][item.Location] || 0) + item.Value;
    ['Month', 'Location'].forEach(function (key) {
        total[key] = total[key] || {};
        total[key][item[key]] = (total[key][item[key]] || 0) + item.Value;
    });
    total.total += item.Value;
});

console.log(grouped);
console.log(total);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```